# substitute for dairy products?

Tags: chocolate, yogurt, dairy-free, peanut-butter

I am a cookery student. As a part of my course, I need to create dietary menus. I have chosen dairy free. Because I am allegy to dairy it can help me to understand how I can produce dairy free food. I have to ask questions to a proffesional advisor for reference.

First of all, I am wondering what I can use instead of yogurt. I know I can use soy milk or almond milk instead of milk from cow. But is it possible to make yogurt and cheese from soy or almond? or what can I use instead?

Secondly, as I know, dark chocolate is dairy free but someone said it can be contained dairy. Is that right?

Finally, I show one menu to my teacher. After he looked at it, he said that did I checked peanut butter contains dairy or not. What kinds of brands of peanut butter are dairy free?

Comment: Welcome! We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum (see the [tour]) and it works best here if you ask one specific question a time. On top of that, for most ingredients the best substitutes depend on the recipe. (In particular there are tons of things you can do with yogurt or cheese.) So if you could separate this into multiple questions, and add some additional details about what you're actually trying to make, we'll be able to help you out much better.

Comment: I should also mention, questions tend to be better received with a bit of research effort first. Google is your friend here; you can quickly for example find that [soy yogurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soy_yogurt) exists, there are [plenty of cheese alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_analogue), and so on; that might help give you a better starting point for your questions.

Comment: Unashamedly playing devil's advocate: Multiple questions also work better with the question rating and reputation system here :)

Comment: @rackandboneman Not sure how that's devil's advocate; it's just working as intended that the reputation system rewards you for doing the right thing.

Comment: All peanut butters are dairy-free. (Except for maybe some specialty flavored kinds?) Butter in the name just refers to the consistency. Dark chocolate may or may not contain dairy. Check the ingredients. Fake yogurts exist, using soy or other. I'd just buy them directly instead of making my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to Yoghurt preparation is Yes, yoghurt can be prepared via Soy milk. Soy yogurt can be prepared at home using the same method as dairy yogurt. One tablespoon of sugar per 1 liter of unsweetened soy milk may be added to promote bacterial fermentation. Soy milk on its own lacks the lactose (milk sugar) that is the basic food for the yogurt bacteria.
Also cheese can be made using Soy milk Using 2 liters of Soy Milk, 3 lemons and 3/4 cup boiling water.
- Line the sieve with the cheesecloth and place on top of the bowl
- Heat the milk in pan until it starts forming bubbles; turn off the heat.
- Squeeze the lemons into the heated water and pour 1/3 of it to the milk. Stir and close the pan for 5 minutes. This will start the solidification process. Now again add the half of water of the left over. Again close for 5 minutes. Add the rest of water, stir, close and wait for 15 minutes.
Yolla, cheese is ready.
About Chocolate, there are some dairy free and some with milk or vegan.
I would like you to read about alternative to cow's milk as this might give you some other options to consider. Consider reading the [Dairy Milk Alternatives](http://www.friedcoffee.com/cows-milk-alternatives-for-your-coffee-cup/) Hope, it helps.